# How does one obtain tortoise coordinates by integrating with GNU Scientific Library (GSL)?

Tags: computational-physics, coordinate-transform, gsl

I’m trying to to obtain the values of the tortoise coordinates (Eddington-Finkelstein Coordinates) integrating the expression:
$\frac{dr^*}{dr} = (1 - rS/r)^{-1}$
using the GNU Scientific Library (GSL). I know that the analytical expression is
$r* = r + rs·ln(r/rS - 1)$
so I can compare both results: analytical and integrated.

Unfortunately, the integrated solution seems rotated

[image]

but even if I rotate the graph, the result is shifted…

[image]

If I add 2 constants the graphs are the same

[image]

My question are:

1. why the calculated is rotated?
2. And why if I rotated the graph it’s still shifted? (with the values -x + 10.605, -yxCalculated[i] + rS) both graphs overlap)

I need to know how to do this calculations because in the case of Black Hole Bounce or Wormholes we usually don't have an analytical expression.

Here it’s my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <gsl/gsl_errno.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_odeiv2.h>

#define SYS_DIM 1
#define NODES 10001
#define SCH_MIN_INF -10000
#define SCH_PLU_INF 10000

struct yxParams
{
  double rS;  /* Schwarzschild radius */
};
double rS = 2;
/*
  I refer to r* as y and r as x:
    r = x
    r* = y
  So yx = r*(r) and xy = r(r*)
*/
double yxAnalytical[NODES];
double yxCalculated[NODES];

/**
  @brief  ODE IV 1st grade to solve y[x]'

  @param  t     Independent variable
  @param  y[]   Left side of the 1st grade system of equations
  @param  sys[] Right side of the 1st grade system of equations
*/
int
funcY(double t,
      const double y[],
      double sys[],
      void* params)
{
  struct yxParams *par = (struct yxParams*)params;
  double rS = (par->rS);

  (void)(t);
  double x0 = y[0];

  assert(x0 != 0);
  sys[0] = 1.0/(1.0 - rS/x0);

  return GSL_SUCCESS;
}

/**
  @brief  r*(r) integration... so the inverse r(r*) tortoise coordinates.
          We do this because it's easier to get an analytic expression from
          r*(r) that from r(r*)

  @param  IN, a: interval lower limit
  @param  IN, b: interval upper limit
  @param  IN, n: number of subintervals
  @param  IN, ic: Initial condition
  @param  OUT, yx[]: Array with the integration values
*/
int
yx_integration(double a, double b, int n, double iC)
{
  int status = GSL_SUCCESS;

  double h = (b - a)/n;

  double x0 = a;
  double x1 = x0 + h;
  double epsAbs = 0;
  double epsRel = 1e-6;

  struct yxParams params = {rS};

  gsl_odeiv2_system sys = {funcY, NULL, SYS_DIM, &params};
  const gsl_odeiv2_step_type* T = gsl_odeiv2_step_rkf45;
  gsl_odeiv2_driver* d = gsl_odeiv2_driver_alloc_y_new (&sys, T, h, epsAbs, epsRel);

  double y[1] = {iC};
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < NODES; i++)
  {
    status = gsl_odeiv2_driver_apply(d, &x0, x1, y);
    x0 = x1;
    x1 = x0 + h;

    if (status != GSL_SUCCESS)
    {
      printf ("error, return value = %d\n", status);
      break;
    }
    else
    {
      double tmp = y[0];

      if(_isnanf(tmp) || isinf(tmp))
      {
        tmp = SCH_MIN_INF;
      }

      yxCalculated[i] = tmp;
    }
  }
  gsl_odeiv2_driver_free(d);

  return status;
}

/**
  @brief  Tortoise analytical expression: r*(r)

  @param  IN a: interval lower limit
  @param  IN h: step
*/
void
yx_analytical(double a, double h)
{
  double x = a;
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < NODES; i++)
  {
    double tortoise = x + rS*log(x/rS - 1);

    if(_isnanf(tortoise))
    {
      tortoise = SCH_MIN_INF;
    }
    yxAnalytical[i] = tortoise;
    x += h;
  }
}

/**
  @brief  Save the data so we can plot it

  @param  IN x
  @param  IN h
*/
void
txt_data(double x, double h)
{
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("data.txt", "w");

  fprintf(fp, "#%32s %32s %32s %32s\n", "yxAnalytical", "x", "yxCalculated", "x");
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < NODES; i++)
  {
    /*
    If we plot 'yx vs x', we're plotting the inverse function... so we're plotting
    r(r*) the tortoise coordinates xy[].

    Q1) yxCalculated is rotated with respect yxAnalytical. Why?
    Q2) if I plot (if I'm not wrong this implies rotating 180º the graph)
        fprintf(fp, "%.32f %.32f %.32f %.32f\n", yxAnalytical[i], x, -x, -yxCalculated[i]);
        both graphs are practically the same... but not equal. I need to shift the graph
        fprintf(fp, "%.32f %.32f %.32f %.32f\n", yxAnalytical[i], x, -x + 10.605, -yxCalculated[i] + rS);
        so calculations seems to be in the right direction... but certainly something is really wrong
    */
    fprintf(fp, "%.32f %.32f %.32f %.32f\n", yxAnalytical[i], x, yxCalculated[i], x);
    /*
      Trick to overlap the graphs...
    *
    fprintf(fp, "%.32f %.32f %.32f %.32f\n", yxAnalytical[i], x, -x + 10.605, -yxCalculated[i] + rS);
    */
    x += h;
  }
  fclose(fp);
}

/**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int main()
{
  /*
  To our purposes these values are enough far away from the BH.
  These values are for the numerical integration.
  */
  double a = -150;
  double b = 150;
  int n = NODES - 1;
  double h = (b - a)/n;

  /* Do calculations... */
  yx_analytical(a, h);
  yx_integration(a, b, n, a);

  /* Save the data in a text file */
  txt_data(a, h);

  return 0;
}
```

**I'll answer myself**

This's my final code (integrating backwards). I've added the jacobian and solve a little issue (misconception) with my funcY.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <gsl/gsl_errno.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_odeiv2.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>

#define SYS_DIM 1
#define NODES 10001
#define SCH_MIN_INF -10000
#define SCH_PLU_INF 10000

struct yxParams
{
  double rS;  /* Schwarzschild radius */
};
double rS = 2;
/*
  I refer to r* as y and r as x:
    r = x
    r* = y
  So yx = r*(r) and xy = r(r*)
*/
double yxAnalytical[NODES];
double yxCalculated[NODES];

/**
  @brief  yx[] jacobian, so you can use implicit methods

  rS/(r^2*(1 - rS/r)^2)
*/
int
jacoY(double r,
     const double y[],
     double *dfdy,
     double dfdt[],
     void *params)
{
  (void)(y);
  struct yxParams *par = (struct yxParams*)params;
  double rS = (par->rS);

  gsl_matrix_view dfdy_mat = gsl_matrix_view_array(dfdy, 1, 1);
  gsl_matrix *m = &dfdy_mat.matrix;
  /*gsl_matrix_set (m, 0, 0, -rS/(r*r*(rS/r - 1)*(rS/r - 1)));*/
  gsl_matrix_set (m, 0, 0, -rS/(r*r*(1 - rS/r)*(1 - rS/r)));
  dfdt[0] = 0.0;

  return GSL_SUCCESS;
}

/**
  @brief  ODE IV 1st grade to solve y[x]'

  @param  x     Independent variable
  @param  y[]   Left side of the 1st grade system of equations
  @param  sys[] Right side of the 1st grade system of equations
*/
int
funcY(double x,
      const double y[],
      double sys[],
      void* params)
{
  struct yxParams *par = (struct yxParams*)params;
  double rS = (par->rS);

  assert(x != 0);

  sys[0] = 1.0/(1.0 - rS/x);

  return GSL_SUCCESS;
}

/**
  @brief  r*(r) integration... so the inverse r(r*) tortoise coordinates.
          We do this because it's easier to get an analytic expression from
          r*(r) that from r(r*)

  @param  IN, a: interval lower limit
  @param  IN, b: interval upper limit
  @param  IN, n: number of subintervals
  @param  IN, ic: Initial condition
  @param  OUT, yx[]: Array with the integration values
*/
int
yx_integration(double a, double b, int n, double iC)
{
  int status = GSL_SUCCESS;

  double h = (b - a)/n;

  double x0 = a;
  double x1 = x0 + h;
  double epsAbs = 0;
  double epsRel = 1e-6;

  struct yxParams params = {rS};

  gsl_odeiv2_system sys = {funcY, jacoY, SYS_DIM, &params};
  const gsl_odeiv2_step_type* T = gsl_odeiv2_step_rk8pd;  /* rkf45, rkck, rk8pd; rk4imp bsimp msadams msbdf */
  gsl_odeiv2_driver* d = gsl_odeiv2_driver_alloc_y_new (&sys, T, h, epsAbs, epsRel);

  double y[1] = {iC};
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < NODES; i++)
  {
    status = gsl_odeiv2_driver_apply(d, &x0, x1, y);
    x0 = x1;
    x1 = x0 + h;

    if (status != GSL_SUCCESS)
    {
      printf ("error, return value = %d\n", status);
      printf("x0: %f, y[0]: %f", x0, y[0]);
      break;
    }
    else
      yxCalculated[i] = y[0];
  }
  gsl_odeiv2_driver_free(d);

  return status;
}

/**
  @brief  Tortoise analytical expression: r*(r)

  @param  IN a: interval lower limit
  @param  IN h: step
*/
void
yx_analytical(double a, double h)
{
  double x = a;
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < NODES; i++)
  {
    double tortoise = x + rS*log(x/rS - 1);

    if(isnan(tortoise))
      tortoise = SCH_MIN_INF;
    yxAnalytical[i] = tortoise;
    x += h;
  }
}

/**
  @brief  Save the data so we can plot it

  @param  IN x
  @param  IN h
*/
void
txt_data(double x, double h)
{
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("data.txt", "w");

  int n = NODES - 1;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < NODES; i++)
  {
    fprintf(fp, "%.32f %.32f %.32f %.32f\n", yxAnalytical[i], x, yxCalculated[n - i], x);
    x += h;
  }
  fclose(fp);
}

/**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int main()
{
  /*
  To our purposes these values are enough far away from the BH.
  These values are for the numerical integration.
  */
  double a = -150;
  double b = 150;
  int n = NODES - 1;
  double h = (b - a)/n;

  /* Do calculations... */
  yx_analytical(a, h);
  /*yx_integration(b, a, n, b);*/
  /* Unfortunately we need and exact IC... we cannot use the tortoise approximation
  rS = r enough far away... */
  double ic = b + rS*log(b/rS - 1);
  yx_integration(b, a, n, ic);
  /* Save the data in a text file */
  txt_data(a, h);

  return 0;
}
```

So if we use the tortoise approximation for the initial condition, where rS = r far away, we've got a curve with a perfect shape... but with an offset
[image] note that at the horizon we cannot continue with the integration (but is ok).
If we use the exact IC, where $r_* = r + rS·ln(r/rS - 1)$ we get the exact curve [image] except that again, we cannot continue the integration at the horizon.

Comment: I'll answer myself...

It seems that we have 2 options:

1) Integrate forward but from the horizont + delta
...
a = m_rS + 1e-6;
yx_integration(a, b, n, a);
2) Integrate backward, but using an analytic value... you cannot use the tortoise approximation where r* = r when r is big because of the shift
...
yx_integration(b, a, n, b);

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is your initial condition from the theory? How is it that you do not get run-time errors for the evaluation of the logarithm for negative arguments? As you impose in the code $y(a)=a$ for $a=-150$, you will of course get a solution $y(x)=x+\log((x-r_s)/(a-r_s))$ (see below), which is clearly different from the reference solution that has no value at $x=a$.

---

Then again, the differential equation you actually solve is
$$
y'(x)=\frac1{1-r_s/y(x)}=\frac{y(x)}{y(x)-r_s}
\\
\implies y'(x)-r_s\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)}=1
\\
\implies y(x)-r_s\ln|y(x)|=x+c
\\
\implies y(x)e^{-y(x)/r_S}=Ce^{-x/r_S}
$$
which can be sort-of solved using the Lambert-W function. (If $y(a)=a$, then $C=a$ follows.)

---

To provide contrast, the ODE or integration problem as guessed from the question text reads as
$$
\frac{dy(x)}{dx}=\frac1{1-r_S/x}=\frac{x}{x-r_S}=1+\frac{r_S}{x-r_S}.
$$
This integrates nicely to
$$
r^*=y(x)=x+r_s\ln|x-r_S|+C
$$
which has the formula of the reference solution as one of its cases, whatever the initial condition for it was.

To implement this you need to be careful in what are the dependent and independent variables. Then the ODE function should be implemented as

```c
int
funcY(double x,
      const double y[],
      double sys[],
      void* params)
{
  struct yxParams *par = (struct yxParams*)params;
  double rS = (par->rS);

  assert(x != rS);
  sys[0] = x/(x - rS);

  return GSL_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: My initial condition was 'a = -150', because I was integrating forward... but it was a bad idea... Yes, logs for reals <= 0 doesn't exists but I'm 'capturing' this issue with the 'isnan(xxx)' so I can deal with this. My intention is to solve numerically this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddington%E2%80%93Finkelstein_coordinates using the natural units https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius where G and c = 1, so the Schwarzschild radius, rS, is 2M. Thank you very much for the answer Dr Lehmann.